# Must I vote on all candidates in the election?

Tags: support, moderator-election

If I understand it correctly, this time around, we have a different voting system in [the moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election). Instead of selecting the "top 3" candidates as previously, I can individually vote for or against each of them.

Yet, I see that some candidates are good (=>vote for), some are bad (=>vote against), but some are neither (I'd prefer to not vote at all).

But, from the implementation's point of view (which I cannot see), **is my voting process considered "complete"** (whatever that means in technical terms) **only after I've cast a vote for/against each of the candidates?**

Apart from getting the badge (a small, but still pleasant thing), I primarily wonder **what the system's designers are expecting me to do. Do they expect me to rank candidates on a two-point or a three-point scale?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it is the same as last time. This is the **primary**. You can vote up or down on each candidate, or you can skip a candidate if you want. Later (4 days from the time of this post), in the real **election**, you can rank your top three choices.

From the text on [the election page itself](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8):

> In the **primary** phase, all nominees advance to preliminary community voting. Any community member with **150** reputation may vote in the primary.
>
> There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per
>   candidate. The candidate vote scores are all public. Initial voting
>   should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.
>
> All candidates are displayed in random order.
>
> The primary is not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion
>   at any point during the primary phase.
>
> After 4 days, the top **10** candidates based on primary vote score
>   proceed onward to the **election** phase.

For the **election** phase,

> In the **election** phase, 10 candidates advance to final community
>   voting. Candidates are displayed in random order.
>
> Any community member with **150** reputation may vote in the election.
>   Each voter may select up to three candidates. Please make your
>   selections in order of preference, with the most desirable candidate
>   as first choice.
>
> We will calculate the winners using OpenSTV with the Meek STV method,
>   which automatically weights users' votes in the way that does the most
>   good for the candidates they have selected, in order of preference.
>
> When the election is complete, the ballot file will be freely
>   downloadable from this page for the life of the site. Individual
>   users' voting choices are always private; only the aggregated tally
>   will be made public.

Comment: Oh, I see. I must've missed the "primary" phase last time then. The notification got me confused - I think it's the same as the one for the "final" stage.

Comment: The notification for the primary says, `Please cast your primary vote in the Stack Overflow 2016 community moderator election.` For the general, it will say something like, `Please cast your vote in the Stack Overflow 2016 community moderator election.`

Comment: Well, _almost_ the same :) Maybe the 2nd one should mention "final phase" or something to make it clearly distinctive. "Primary" is a synonym for "main", after all.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev This may be a language barrier issue. "Primary election" has a very well-defined meaning in English: it's a preliminary vote to narrow down candidates for an office. It implies that there will be a later election to make the final selection among the remaining candidates. It would be hard to change the wording without also changing the meaning.

Comment: Indeed it is. This is the first time I hear this to be a specific term - and I'm quite proficient in English. Likely because minor details of foreign political systems never interested me. Here in Russia, we use the equivalent of "preliminary" (there is an expression, "primary sieve/selection", but it's used for choosing people for subordinate rather than governing positions).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Primary is not necessarily a synonym for 'main'. It also means 'first'. For example: primary school, secondary school, etc.

Comment: I came here because I totally overlooked that yellow box on the right, from which you cite. Maybe others had the same problem!?

Comment: @canaaerus The three phases (nomination, primary, and election) are mentioned in several places on the page, including in the main text above the candidates, the box on the right, and the three tabs. There are only so many ways to call attention to it without either hoping people read the explanations that are there or resorting to obnoxious formatting to get attention.

Comment: @EdCottrell: My confusion was not about what phases there are, but about what the voting mode for the current phase is. This is explained quite well in that box, but not in the main text. I would suggest creating a help page explaining all about the moderator elections and adding a link to it on the election page.

Comment: @canaaerus We do assume that people will read at least some of the information on the page. There's no need for yet another page explaining information that is already on the election page itself. And throughout the site, the boxes on the right provide information like this: what am I looking at, how do I use/format it, and what do I do next? Obviously, sometimes people miss it. But for the most part, the current setup has worked well.